# Error loading xslt file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, xslt

I have an asp.net-mvc web application. My controller has a class that has a method to transform a xml using xslt file. In XslCompiledTransform.Load, I am passing the Uri of my xslt file. The xslt file is under Models->Services. When I run the application locally, it is throwing me a FileNotFoundException which says "Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\IISExpress\Namespace.Models.Services.example.xslt". My code snippet looks like,

```
XslCompiledTransform xslTransformRequest = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslTransformRequest.Load("Namespace.Models.Services.example.xslt");
```

Could someone guide me through this?

Comment: Seems like it is looking for the xslt file under IISExpress directory. How could I make it look for the file in my solution ?

Comment: I got it resolved by using Server.MapPath() instead of directly specifying the file name.